# How to update particular file in Azure storage container using azcopy

Tags: azure-container-service, azcopy, azure-storage-account

Problem statement : Currently we have a 2GB blob container ( zip format ) in Azure Storage where it is used for development artifacts, further this blob is used in pipeline to deploy the artifact in to the VM. Is there any possibility to update particular  file in 2GB blob without downloading the 2gb blob in my local and change the code and zip the blob and upload it in container?

Is azcopy fulfill my requirement? if yes what would be the commands to be used?

Answer (score 1):

> Is azcopy fulfill my requirement? if yes what would be the commands to
> be used?

No, no such operation. Unzip file is needed. Azure Blob Storage will not do the unzipping for you. You need to go through some background process (could be WebJobs, Functions, Worker Roles, or Virtual Machines), download the zip file, unzip it, edit, zip and then re-upload.

Related functions are just in the to-do list, not even on the agenda:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3388309-http-compression-support-for-azure-storage-service

So you can give up considering this approach.